# Android Studio automatic created Image Asset in folder midmap-xxxhdpi but name of icon appears in red (= error/not added?)

Tags: android

I just added my first icon for my app to my project. I did it by right clicking on the res folder and then selecting the option Image Asset which lets you create an icon on different resolutions and automatically adds them to the appropriate mipmap-folders.

Now I get the name of the image displayed in red in the folder midmap-xxxhdpi, maybe it's also useful to say that I got VCS running. I got no problems with all the other images in the different folders under res. What is causing the text to be displayed in red?

ps: also the ic_launcher-web.png is displayed in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "-" is not a valid resource name character

remove "-" from the pic name, and clean your project.

Comment: Android studio created that name by itself so that would be very very weird. Are you sure?

Comment: i'm talking about "ic_launcher-web.png"

Comment: I was talking about that too. It created that too.

Comment: if you are going to use "ic_launcher-web.png" in your code/xml then you have to rename it..

Comment: try cleaning your project: go to build >> clean project

Comment: Okay I am not planning to. I just want that on high resolution displays the mimap-xxxhdpi will be used. Rebuilding the project did nothing.